# in javascript, using callback functions recursively for loop control - is this dangerous?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, scope

in the following code cannot use a `for` loop over the array since each step is nonblocking and requires a callback function

Theory of Operation: A form submit calls `verify()` where `el` is the HTMLFormElement and `nextFunc` is the callback function.  each element contained in the form is verified with `verifyCol()`, breaking out to `nextFunc(err)` on the first error returned, or, when done, to `nextFunc()`.

```
// verify as called from post
Post.prototype.verify = function( el, nextFunc ) {
        var post = this;     
        var arr = this.entryArr(el);
        (function verifyOne( i ) {
                if( i >= arr.length ) nextFunc();
                else post.colVerify( arr[i], function(err) {
                        if( err ) nextFunc( err );
                        else verifyOne( i+1 );
                } );    
        })(0);          
}
```

This approach makes sense to me (although suspiciously looks like Lisp).

Is this the correct paradigm here?  Are there any dangers in calling callback functions recursively?

Comment: AFAIK named function expressions are not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaScript *is* a lisp variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (descendant from scheme), that is why it looks like lisp.

There is no recursion in the code above (in the strictest definition of recursion) if the `post` function is a callback function from a HTTP request -- the functions are simply handles which are kept as references and invoked though the event queue when the HTTP post returns with data.

Whether recursion can be used in JavaScript for loop recursion is depending on whther the JavaScript Interpreter have implemented [tail-call-optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) but most JavaScript implementations (add a comment if you know of any) does not have that implemented, so generally loop recursion (that is calling the function without putting the call on the event queue) may cause problems if the call stack becomes too deep.

In your case, the verifyOne call is never called until the post comes back from the previous call, and hence your loop is through the event queue

The program paradigm look ok and textbook-like to me.

Comment: thanks much - although the "textbook-like" make me a little nervous ;)

Comment: Where does "Java Interpreter" come from? Shouldn't that be "JavaScript Interpreter"?